# Is it Possible to use Custom Query from Google Sheets Bigquery to consult with only one parameter

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm Trying to make a consult using a single parameter in Google Sheets

Tried to use UNNEST but ask to use an Array, trying to call the IDs with {} but still wont work

For some reason I cannot cast the @ID the right way

The Cell I'm using as Parameter
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JipwY.png

The Error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW3jP.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.